# Is this conversion of an INT32BE macro to a constexpr correct?

Tags: c++, constexpr, preprocessor-directive

I have the following macro and wanted to convert it to a `constexpr` as apparently it's a better approach:

```
#define INT32BE(x) (x[0] << 24 | x[1] << 16 | x[2] << 8 | x[3])
```

Attempt:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto Int32BE(T array [])
{
    return array[0] << 24 | array[1] << 16 | array[2] << 8 | array[3];
}
```

This is intended to be used in the following way:

```
const auto address = Int32BE(data.Address);
```

The definition of `Address` is as follows:

```
UCHAR Address[4];
```

It does work as expected but I'm not totally sure about how it should be written.

**Question:**

Is this `constexpr` to read a 32-bit integer from an array written correctly ?

Comment: Neither the macro nor the function will work correctly on platforms with 16-bit `int`s.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Which is presumably the origin of the name: `Int32BE` suggests (at least, to me) that it's for use with 32-bit, Big-Endian integers.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yes of course, you're right, I will see if I can 'upgrade' my constexpr to check array bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot speak from a 'language-lawyer' perspective, but the `constexpr` you have given compiles without warning in the following code, with both `MSVC` and `clang-cl`:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

template <typename T>
constexpr auto Int32BE(T array[]) {
    return array[0] << 24 | array[1] << 16 | array[2] << 8 | array[3];
}

int main() {
    unsigned char Address[4] = { 0x22, 0xAA, 0x11, 0xBB };
    const auto address = Int32BE(Address);
    printf("%08X\n", address);
    return 0;
}
```

Further, the output is the expected value (`22AA11BB`).

Comment: Fair enough, I'll stick to it :)